# How to prepend a line to all files in a directory?

Tags: sed, printf

I have a directory called `backup` with file extensions `*.sql`. The thing I want to do is to prepend a line to all sql files in the directory `backup`.

I did `echo 'use my_db;' >> backup/*.sql`, which didn't work.

I tried the below but don't know what to do next:

```
ls backup/*.sql | xargs echo "use my_db;"
```

Any solution to prepend that line?

Comment: You may find [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-prepend-text-lines-to-file/) useful.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
for sql in backup/*.sql; do
    sed -i '1i\use my_db;' "$sql"
done
```

With standard `sed`:

```
for sql in backup/*.sql; do
    sed '1i\
use my_db;
' "$sql" >"$sql.bak" && mv "$sql.bak" "$sql"
done
```

This would do a in-place editing of each `.sql` file in `backup`.  The editing command inserts a line before the first line in each file.

This assumes that the pattern `backup/*.sql` only matches the files that you want to edit.

---

Using `echo` and `cat`:

```
for sql in backup/*.sql; do
    { echo 'use my_db;'; cat "$sql"; } >"$sql.tmp" && mv "$sql.tmp" "$sql"
done
```

In this loop, we first output the line that we'd like to prepend to the file, then the contents of the file.  This goes into a temporary file which is then renamed.

---

The command

```
echo 'use my_db;' >> backup/*.sql
```

would expand to something like

```
echo 'use my_db;' >> backup/file1.sql backup/file2.sql backup/file3.sql
```

which is the same as

```
echo 'use my_db;' backup/file2.sql backup/file3.sql >> backup/file1.sql
```

which would append the given strings to `backup/file1.sql`.

Your second command would not modify any files.

Comment: IIRC `-i` implies `-s` in GNU sed - so it should be possible to skip the loop and just do `sed -i '1i\user mydb' backup/*.sql` (`ARG_MAX` notwithstanding)

Answer (score 15):

#### Solution

`sed -i '1 i\use my_db' backup/*.sql`

#### Explanation

`sed -i` Keep the changes in the files, do not write them to `stdout`.

`1` - When `sed` is positioned on the first line.

`i` - Insert the following line.

`backup/*.sql` Files on which `sed` will perform.

Comment: Will this overwrite the first line of every file? Is there a way to add to the first line moving the previous first line to the second line?

Comment: @ConnorLeech, this will **insert** the line `use my_db` as the first line and move the previously first line as the second line after insertion. If you wanted to **replace/overwrite** the first line, you would use `c\use my_db`. You can always omit the `-i` to see what `sed` does, without doing the permanent changes in file(s).

Answer (score -2):

You could iterate over every file in that folder.

```
for item in $(ls backup/ | grep "*.sql")
do
echo "use my_db;" >> $item
done
```

Comment: Four issues: The regular expression `*.sql` matches a literal `*`. You should not parse the output of `ls`. The text is appended, not prepended. The variable expansion is not quoted.

Comment: What about parsing an `awk` output?  I will face the same trouble there, even if `grep` is used to match `sql$` as regexp, isn't it?

Comment: @Kusalananda Always better to quote, just in case, but I believe that variables used in redirections are not wordsplit, to be fair. However, Kyrie001, even if `$(ls backup/ | grep "*.sql")` were to work (which it won't for 5 issues it has, 3 of which are for using `ls`), the intent could've been completely captured by using `backup/*.sql` in its place. i.e. `for item in backup/*.sql`

Comment: As to what those 5 issues are (provided merely to help you improve your coding): 1) `ls` output is not portable, for example GNU ls now does bash shell quoting by default; 2) depending on how the ls implementation outputs special characters in filenames, you'll have to parse them or they might even not be recoverable if they were all replaced with `?`s; 3) the result is fed line by line and filtered by grep when filenames could consist of more than 1 line; 4) the grep regex is wrong; 5) the output of the whole pipeline is then wordsplit for the `for` loop.

Comment: @JoL No, the shell will not perform word splitting on the expanded value of the variable in that case, but it _will_ perform filename globbing on the value. Having said that, any globbing would already have been performed by the loop head...

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for that; I didn't know globbing would be done. I'm actually quite shocked. I can't believe it's even done after command substitution. On the not being performed in the redirection, if there are files which names have globs, I can imagine globbing being expanded in both places. In this code it would be different because, Kyrie001, I just noticed, `$item` doesn't include `backup/` so it's refering to files in `backup/..`. That's issue #6 :). I've learned plenty here.

Comment: As an example for how globbing can be expanded multiple times. In a directory with files `*` and `f`, `for item in $(echo *); do echo $item; done`, will print `f` 3 times instead of 1.

Comment: @JoL Or if a file has `\*` in its name... possibly.

Comment: @JoL I hope one of the things you've learned is to use zsh. No word splitting or glob evaluations unless you have the options on (why on earth would you?) or ask for it explicitly.

Comment: @Kevin You're too late on the recomendation. :) I've been using zsh for like 6 or 7 years. I only use bash for the scripting portability.